# Oracle EXE application runs on developer PC but not on other users' PCs. Why?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, dll, oracle11g

I am developing a Windows application that connects to Oracle DB.

The machine I am developing the application on has Oracle 6i installed with SQLPlus and Toad to access Oracle by command or graphical interface. 
The same set up is true across all other computers in my work place.

The only difference is that my pc has Visual Studio and Oracle 10g ODP.Net libraries to make the development of Oracle Application possible using Visual Studio.

I made sure to include `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file along with the EXE in the same path to reduce dependency on default paths/ etc.

The finished EXE file runs as expected on my computer, but whenever I publish it to the other computers, I get the following error message:

```
The type intializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.
```

I tried to change the version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from 2.111.6.20  to 10.2.0.100. 
Again, it ran perfectly on my PC but gave the following exception on other PCs:

`Unable to load DLL 'OraOps10.dll': the specified module could not be found.`

I copied the said file above from my pc and included it in the published folder of the EXE but the same error message appeared, as if it invisible to the .Net application.

All computers have Windows 7 and all of them are 32bit.

Is there a way to make the application connect to Oracle regardless of the libraries or Oracle version installed locally on the computer? (The same way Toad works whether it detects Oracle 6i or 10g installed)?

I can't install the Oracle 10g ODP.Net libraries on all computers.

Comment: From what Ive read the oracle libraries would need to be on each pc that runs it.

Comment: I think you will need to install Oracle client on each machine. Why can't you install odp.net? Seems contrary to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer oracle 6i client is already installed on all computers. All of them can run SQLPlus and Toad for Oracle.

Comment: Sure, but .net would require more. Not sure if Oracle 6i is still in support ;)